# Creating a vba loop that grabs cell values

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to create a macro for vba that grabs values entered in my A column of cells 1-1000, and then takes those values and plugs them into an function.

Rather than define a 1000 different values as:

```
x1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value

x2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value

x3 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A3").Value
```

... etc

and then plugging them into my function

`Dim dy As Integer, fx As Integer
dy = Range("B2").Value - Range("B1").Value
fx= dy*(x1+x2+x3....)`

is there someway I can create a do loop that runs from cell A1 to A1000 grabbing each of their own values and plugging it into my function? Here's what I have so far but I'm not sure how I would have it grab the values entered in the cells.

```
xi = 1
Do
xi = 1 + xi
If xi = 1000 Then Exit Do
Count = Count + 1

Loop
```

Comment: Can you share the function?

Comment: May try loop something like this
`fx=0` : `For i=1 to 1000` : `fx= fx + Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A"& i).Value` : `Next I` : `fx=dy*Fx`
Pl be sure all the values are numeric

Comment: @VBasic2008 I edited the original question with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'create a zero-based array o9f the values in A1:A1000
dim x as variant
with Worksheets("Sheet1")
    x = application.transpose(.range("A1:A1000").value)
end with

'sum all of x
dim i as long, sumX as double
for i = lbound(x) to ubound(x)
    sumX = sumX + x(i)
next i

'another way to sum A1:A1000
with Worksheets("Sheet1")
    sumX = application.sum(.range("A1:A1000").value)
end with

'your function
Dim dy As long, fx As long
with Worksheets("Sheet1")
    dy = .Range("B2").Value - .Range("B1").Value
end with
fx = dy * sumX
```

Answer (score 0):

Below Query Works for you. The code flexible to get the row count in column "A". No need to hard code the upper bound value

```
Dim dy As Integer, fx As Integer, iCellSum As Integer
Sub Main()
    iRowCount = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    iCellSum = 0
    For i = 1 To iRowCount
        iCellSum = iCellSum + Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
    Next

    dy = Range("B2").Value - Range("B1").Value

    fx = dy * iCellSum

End Sub
```